# Sound events in Gnome 3

Tags: audio, gnome3, gnome-shell

I've installed Gnome 3 yesterday. I use Gnome Shell.

There are no any sound when a window closes and no any sound when I switch windows.

Can sound be added (at least when I close a window)?